# Loading bar pygame

Tags: python, pygame

How do you make a loading bar / progress bar with pygame, where you will load all the resources before the game starts?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking how to draw and animate a progress bar, you would simply draw increasingly wide rectangles onto the surface, with the width proportional to the progress:

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), pygame.Rect(left,top,maxwidth*progress,height))
```

You could also draw a frame around the progress bar with something like:

```
pygame.draw.rect(surface, (128,128,128), pygame.Rect(left,top,maxwidth,height), 1)
```

The last argument controls the size of a border around the rectangle

If you have a sprite that you want to load ahead of time, you could add it to a list for later rendering:

```
sprites.append(pygame.image.load(filename))
```

or refer to it by name:

```
playersprite = pygame.image.load(filename)
```

It just depends on how you intend to use the loaded resources. To interface with the progress bar, you could increment `progress` for each loaded resource.

Comment: A handy alternative for sprites.append: sprite.Group.add()

Comment: Every time you load something, have a counter variable increment by x. This will be the percentage done.